# Enable ANSI compatibility when dumping inserts with mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I need to dump data with mysqldump and have it use ANSI quoting, so

```
"tablename"
```

instead of

```
`tablename`
```

quoting.

I can't change the server settings and `--compatible` options are not working, nor is `--ansi` a valid option to mysqldump.

How do I set this for the mysqldump session?

I don't want to pipe through sed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_compatible says:

> `--compatible=name`
>
> Produce output that is more compatible with other database systems or with older MySQL servers. **The only permitted value for this option is `ansi`**, which has the same meaning as the corresponding option for setting the server SQL mode.

(emphasis mine)

I just tested this on MySQL 8.0.32 and it works. It does not produce an error, it changes the identifier delimiter to `"` for compatibility with non-MySQL instances.

That's only part of the compatibility you need, though. There are many other statements in the dump output that will not work in other brands of RDBMS.